# Why infrastructure folder does not add automatically in my solution on MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am learning MVC from ASP.NET MVC 5 Live Lessons.

My problem is when instructor create new project he has some additional folders there in his solution but in my solution those folders are not exist, such as `Infrastructure`.

[image: solutions side by side]

I don't know what is the reason behind that. The reason why I am asking this question is that the instructor uses some class from `infrastructure` folder that classes are not exist in my project so that I cant use them.

Can anyone please help me to get rid of this problem?

Comment: MVC-4 does not add an "Infrastructure" folder by default. You can just add whatever additional folders you like to your own project. You have not shown the contents of the Instructors Infrastructure folder, but possibly it contains the files used by Ninject for DI

Comment: A quick google showed [this as a result](https://github.com/cstrahan/codecampserver/tree/master/src) which confirms Stephen's point

Comment: yes sir . i didn't show the contents of the infrastructure folder because instructor didn't show that ..instructor use a interface called IConferencerepository which is in the infrastructure folder...the main reason i asked question is that i cant use IConferencerepository interface ...please See this link ....http://1drv.ms/1dTDW5q